# Is it possible to add terminal command exit status to Gnome top bar?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment, gnome-terminal

Is there any Gnome extension (v45+) that displays the error/success status of a command running in a terminal application after it completes?

What I am looking for is a persistent icon/message/widget on e.g. the top bar instead of a generic transient desktop notification (as currently implemented on Gnome).

Comment: hi! Not sure I understand you correctly: you want to start a process from the terminal, and have a notification icon that shows what it returned, right? Would a simple `program || {program that adds an exclamation mark to the system bar}` work for that use case, i.e. "execute `program`, and if it fails, also execute the thing that adds an icon"?

Comment: Lots of terminal applications push a notification when commands terminate (e.g. Ubuntu/Gnome default behavior). I'm not sure if reporting the exit status is application-specific, but I'd just want to have something on the top bar signaling if a command has terminated, instead of a generic push notification.

Comment: Your best bet is probably the terminal title. You can set with the OSC 0 escape sequence, e.g. `printf '\e]0;title\e\\'; sleep 10`. The `sleep` is there to demonstrate the functionality just in case your shell prompt overrides it. Customize your shell prompt (`PS0`) to include the last command's return value (`$?`).

Comment: @joaocandre I got that, the question is how you're starting things. I ask because I presume it's from the terminal, considering the [tag:gnome-terminal] tag. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, I forgot to mention that on the question (already edited); I was looking for a solution that would work implicitly/without having to run `{program that adds an exclamation mark to the system bar}`.

Answer (score 1):

that should be possible using `yad`. A simple example would be

```bash
(myprogram && yad --notification --image gtk-yes &) || (yad --notification --image dialog-error &)
```

We can of course also put this in a script to make it more user-friendly. Save the below as `systray-notify` somewhere in your `$PATH` and make it executable via `chmod 755 systray-notify`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

( $@  && \
  yad --notification --image gtk-yes &\
) || \
( yad --notification --image dialog-error &)
```

you can then

```bash
systray-notify fsck.vfat -w /dev/sda12
```

you can instead of using one of the icon names from `yad-icon-browser`, like `gtk-yes` or `dialog-error` also use the full path to .svg or .png images.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but (using zenity instead of yad), I get a generic notification dialog, something gnome-terminal already provides me with.

Comment: well, I did say to use `yad` because it allows you to get a notification icon in the taskbar. If you use something else and it doesn't do what my script does, no surprise.

Comment: yad doesn't work on Wayland though, hence why I went for zenity